# Lubuntu 14.04.1 youtube not working without html5

Tags: lubuntu, flash, youtube

I've just installed Lubuntu 14.04.1 and when I tried to go to youtube I coudldn't read a video.

I am using the firefox which is automatically installed when installing lubuntu , the shockwave flash 11.2.202.411 plugin is installed.

I have installed pepperflashplugin-nonfree nothing changed.

Here a screen of what I see when trying to read a video. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsyS9.jpg
There is nothing, no play button, nothing telling me it can't read.

However I just noticed it works fine when using the html5 option https://www.youtube.com/html5/

Is there a problem with flash ? How can I fixed it ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution may be to install ubuntu-restricted-extras.  This should install various plugins and codecs that you may need to get going, all in one easy swoop.

I suggest this because I've noticed an obtuse problem in your question, that you installed pepperflash to use with firefox.  pepperflash is for chromium only; firefox uses a different version of flash (flashplugin-installer).

There is back-story as to why chrome, chromium, and firefox each have different situations regarding flash, and different install procedures.  I suggest the u-r-e package if you want to not get into that.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install `google-chrome-stable` if firefox flash is not working, or you might wanna consider reinstalling firefox like mentioned [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed) and reinstall it.