# I can't play facebook videos on firefox in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, firefox, video, facebook

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 a couple days ago.

I can't play facebook videos on firefox. When I click on the video the page just refreshes and nothing happens.

Ihave no extensions installed and I've already removed firefox and installed it again but the problem still persists. I also have a black screen on twitch, though the audio is fine. On the other hand, videos and twitch work on Chromium

#### What I've tried

- Re-installed firefox
- Re-installed adobe flash player (not sure if did it right)
- Restarted my computer

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed to remove firefox and reinstall.

Comment: I did what it said in that guide. but nothing changes, i still can't play Fb videos

Comment: did you install flash?

Comment: I did install flash.  and i can play youutbe videos.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0403]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p&&index($0,n){p=1}p'`, `aplay -l`, `pactl list short sinks`, and `pactl list sink-inputs | gawk -v name=firefox -v RS='\n\n' 'index($0, name)'`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: The output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package} ${Version}\n' 'gstreamer*-plugins-*' | awk '$1 != "u" && $2 !~ /-dbg$/ { printf("%s\t%s\n", $2, $3) }'` might help too.

Comment: Original poster solved his issue: "I did install flash. and i can play youtube videos. – zakaria hilali Feb 19 at 16:31"

Answer (score 6):

I've had this problem in the past with videos on all versions of Ubuntu & Firefox, YouTube seems to work fine but nothing else like nfl.com, facebook and news websites videos.

I’ve recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it seems to have cured this problem by going to the Ubuntu software icon, and going to the add-ons category, then select the codec tab and [found 12 gstream selections with 6 already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynMBB.jpg). I installed 2 of the first ones, and my problem was solved: I can now play any video from any website.

Comment: https://youtu.be/aPHr_Xm60E4 , YOU TUBE LINK!!!

Comment: Screen shots good,  Videos bad...  **;-)** (Leaving the comment in though) and and edit and a +1

Answer (score 0):

Install the GStreamer OpenCV plugins

`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools`

Comment: how should they do that? explaining why it would help would be nice too