# Activities uses older version of firefox

Tags: firefox, activities-overview

I installed the latest version (67.02) if firefox. In my home directory there is a folder called 'firefox' and if I open it there is an executable file called 'firefox' and if I click it the latest firefox opens. That's how I am typing this. So far so good.

However, if I open Activities and type firefox in the search field, or click on the little squares and look for the firefox icon I get something called 'Firefox Web Browser', with the firefox logo.

If I do it *now* when the new firefox is open, clicking that icon will lead me back to the open version of firefox. However, doing it when firefox is not open yet, this method of opening firefox **will open an older version (52) of firefox that is apparently still on my computer somewhere**. However, I have no idea where this old version is hiding, because searching for firefox using 'files' will only lead me to the new version.

Of course I don't want the old version anymore, but I do want to know where it is hiding. So my questions are:

1. How do I find where on my computer the old version is living?
2. How do I get rid of the old firefox without also destroying the new one?
3. How do I tell 'activities' that the new firefox is the one it should recognize?

Comment: What is the output of the following command in Terminal?: `apt policy firefox`

Comment: E: Invalid operation policy

Comment: (I don't know what it means)

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Likely using prior to 16.04 which is considered off-topic here.. Anyway try `apt-cache policy firefox` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check /usr/share/applications/ for the "old" Firefox. Open the .desktop file and check the Exec line. You will find your old Firefox location. You could also try running:

PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games command firefox

If you still need some data from that profile check https://support.mozilla.org/ro/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles

Moving the /usr/share/applications/Firefox.desktop to $HOME/.local/share/applications and changing Exec and TryExec lines with your "new" Firefox path should also update the version seen by desktop.

Also removing firefox safely is better explained already here:
[Removing Firefox in Ubuntu with all add-ons like it never existed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed)

Comment: Core of the answer indeed is to copy your firefox .desktop file to .local/share/applications and update the `Exec=` line to point to your new firefox.