# How to stop firefox language pack update in Software Updater?

Tags: updates, firefox

I have removed firefox using the most accepted answer on [How to uninstall firefox from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed). And I also manually removed files by searching "firefox" in computer as much as possible. Still in software updater this keeps popping up, please look at image -> [Software updater image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io5A5.png) . What do I do to stop this?

Comment: It looks like an update for the package named `firefox-local-en`.  Can you open a terminal and run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt purge firefox-local-en`?  Before continuing with `y`, review the output in case that command wants to also remove other dependencies you may need.  By getting rid of the package, it shouldn't prompt for any more updates.

Comment: @Nmath ```sudo apt update``` ran as expected. But ```sudo apt purge firefox-local-en``` gave error: ```E: Unable to locate package firefox-local-en```. When I ran ```apt list --upgradable```, the list does not have words "firefox" or "mozilla" in any of the items.