# Nothing is opening in firefox after signing in

Tags: firefox

I just finished installing ubuntu and logged in to firefox with my google account to sync my tabs and history.

But since logging it, I am not able to open anything on firefox, not even settings etc.

I tried various thing including unistalling firefox using steps given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed) and installing it again, but even after doing this I am not able to open anything not even able to login to sync the tabs and histories.

[image]

The omnibar predictions are working fine and showing but on clicking on anything again it is not working.

I am using firefox 89.0 and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

If we open a fresh firefox window, normally we get the new tab page with top sites and highlights but in my case nothing is shown on the window, it is just blank like shown in the screenshot.

If I wait some time, I am getting a crash report from Mozilla Crash Reporter.

```
AbortMessage: ###!!! ABORT: file resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2605
AdapterDeviceID: 0x9b41
AdapterDriverVendor: mesa/iris
AdapterDriverVersion: 20.2.6.0
AdapterVendorID: 0x8086
Add-ons: doh-rollout%40mozilla.org:2.0.0,formautofill%40mozilla.org:1.0.1,pictureinpicture%40mozilla.org:1.0.0,screenshots%40mozilla.org:39.0.1,webcompat%40mozilla.org:22.2.0,default-theme%40mozilla.org:1.2,google%40search.mozilla.org:1.1,amazondotcom%40search.mozilla.org:1.3,wikipedia%40search.mozilla.org:1.1,bing%40search.mozilla.org:1.3,ddg%40search.mozilla.org:1.1
AsyncShutdownTimeout: {"phase":"profile-change-teardown","conditions":[{"name":"Extension shutdown: webcompat@mozilla.org","state":{"state":"Startup: Run manifest, asyncEmitManifestEntry(\"background\")"},"filename":"resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm","lineNumber":2605,"stack":["resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:startup/<:2605","resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.jsm:observe:575"]},{"name":"Extension shutdown: screenshots@mozilla.org","state":{"state":"Startup: Run manifest, asyncEmitManifestEntry(\"background\")"},"filename":"resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm","lineNumber":2605,"stack":["resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:startup/<:2605","resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.jsm:observe:575"]},{"name":"Extension shutdown: pictureinpicture@mozilla.org","state":{"state":"Startup: Run manifest, asyncEmitManifestEntry(\"background\")"},"filename":"resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm","lineNumber":2605,"stack":["resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:startup/<:2605","resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.jsm:observe:575"]},{"name":"Extension shutdown: formautofill@mozilla.org","state":{"state":"Startup: Run manifest, asyncEmitManifestEntry(\"background\")"},"filename":"resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm","lineNumber":2605,"stack":["resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:startup/<:2605","resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.jsm:observe:575"]}]}
AvailablePageFile: 0
AvailablePhysicalMemory: 11548344320
AvailableSwapMemory: 1999630336
AvailableVirtualMemory: 13304782848
BuildID: 20210527174632
ContentSandboxCapabilities: 119
ContentSandboxCapable: 1
ContentSandboxLevel: 4
CrashTime: 1622739064
DOMIPCEnabled: 1
DesktopEnvironment: gnome
EMCheckCompatibility: true
ExperimentalFeatures: browser.startup.homepage.abouthome_cache.enabled,network.cookie.sameSite.laxByDefault,network.cookie.sameSite.noneRequiresSecure,network.cookie.sameSite.schemeful,layout.css.constructable-stylesheets.enabled,layout.css.grid-template-masonry-value.enabled,devtools.inspector.color-scheme-simulation.enabled,devtools.inspector.compatibility.enabled,devtools.webconsole.input.context,devtools.debugger.features.windowless-service-workers,fission.autostart,network.http.http3.enabled,image.avif.enabled,media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.allow-multiple,browser.urlbar.keepPanelOpenDuringImeComposition,dom.forms.inputmode,dom.webgpu.enabled,privacy.webrtc.globalMuteToggles
FramePoisonBase: 9223372036600930304
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1622738996
IsWayland: 0
MozCrashReason: MOZ_CRASH()
Notes: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTSFP(D00-L1000-W00000000-T000) WR? WR+ OMTP? OMTP- libGL.so.1? libGL.so.1+ GL Context? GL Context+ xpcom_runtime_abort(###!!! ABORT: file resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2605)
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 0
ShutdownProgress: profile-change-teardown
StartupCrash: 0
StartupTime: 1622738996
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86-64","buildId":"20210527174632","version":"89.0","vendor":"Mozilla","displayVersion":"89.0","platformVersion":"89.0","xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3","updaterAvailable":false},"partner":{"distributionId":"canonical","distributionVersion":"1.0","partnerId":"ubuntu","distributor":"canonical","distributorChannel":"ubuntu","partnerNames":["ubuntu"]},"system":{"memoryMB":15611,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":8,"cores":4,"vendor":"GenuineIntel","family":6,"model":142,"stepping":12,"l2cacheKB":256,"l3cacheKB":6144,"speedMHz":4400,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3","hasSSSE3","hasSSE4_1","hasSSE4_2","hasAVX","hasAVX2","hasAES"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"5.8.0-53-generic","locale":"en-IN"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null,"type":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null,"type":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null,"type":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"ContentBackend":"Skia","Headless":false,"EmbeddedInFirefoxReality":null,"adapters":[{"description":"Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2)","vendorID":"0x8086","deviceID":"0x9b41","subsysID":null,"RAM":0,"driver":null,"driverVendor":"mesa/iris","driverVersion":"20.2.6.0","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[{"screenWidth":1360,"screenHeight":768}],"features":{"compositor":"webrender","hwCompositing":{"status":"available"},"gpuProcess":{"status":"unused"},"wrQualified":{"status":"available"},"webrender":{"status":"available"},"wrCompositor":{"status":"disabled:FEATURE_FAILURE_DISABLED"},"wrSoftware":{"status":"available"},"openglCompositing":{"status":"available"},"omtp":{"status":"disabled:FEATURE_FAILURE_DISABLED"}}},"appleModelId":null},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":true,"e10sMultiProcesses":8,"fissionEnabled":false,"telemetryEnabled":false,"locale":"en-US","intl":{"requestedLocales":["en-IN"],"availableLocales":["en-US"],"appLocales":["en-US"],"systemLocales":["en-IN"],"regionalPrefsLocales":["en-IN"],"acceptLanguages":["en-US","en"]},"update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":false},"userPrefs":{"browser.search.widget.inNavBar":false,"widget.content.allow-gtk-dark-theme":false,"widget.content.gtk-high-contrast.enabled":true,"browser.search.region":"IN"},"sandbox":{"effectiveContentProcessLevel":4},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":true,"defaultSearchEngine":"google-canonical","defaultSearchEngineData":{"loadPath":"[other]addEngineWithDetails:google@search.mozilla.org","name":"Google","origin":"default","submissionURL":"https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q="}},"profile":{"creationDate":18781,"firstUseDate":18781},"addons":{"activeAddons":{"doh-rollout@mozilla.org":{"version":"2.0.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18778,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"This used to be a Mozilla add-on that supported the roll-out of DoH, but now only exists as a stub t","name":"DoH Roll-Out","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18778},"formautofill@mozilla.org":{"version":"1.0.1","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18778,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":null,"name":"Form Autofill","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18778},"pictureinpicture@mozilla.org":{"version":"1.0.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18778,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"Fixes for web compatibility with Picture-in-Picture","name":"Picture-In-Picture","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18778},"screenshots@mozilla.org":{"version":"39.0.1","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18778,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"Take clips and screenshots from the Web and save them temporarily or permanently.","name":"Firefox Screenshots","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18778},"webcompat@mozilla.org":{"version":"22.2.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18778,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"Urgent post-release fixes for web compatibility.","name":"Web Compatibility Interventions","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18778}},"theme":{},"activeGMPlugins":{"dummy-gmp":{"version":"0.1","userDisabled":false,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1}}},"experiments":{"default-upgradeDialog":{"branch":"upgradeDialog-defaultEnabled","type":"nimbus-default","enrollmentId":"__NO_ENROLLMENT_ID__"},"bug-1693420-rollout-sponsored-top-sites-rollout-release-84-100":{"branch":"active","type":"normandy-prefrollout","enrollmentId":"f03a2c3c-5857-4100-a1b5-88f8565ad6cf"},"bug-1703186-rollout-http3-support-release-88-89":{"branch":"active","type":"normandy-prefrollout","enrollmentId":"eb922719-d793-451c-ad80-5b27fee64eb9"}}}
TelemetrySessionId: 83e2f0a1-ef73-4cae-bade-597e5f91b161
ThreadIdNameMapping: 11965:"IPC I/O Parent",11966:"Timer",11967:"Netlink Monitor",11969:"Permission",11971:"JS Watchdog",11973:"JS Helper",11975:"JS Helper",11977:"JS Helper",11976:"JS Helper",11974:"JS Helper",11978:"JS Helper",11979:"JS Helper",11980:"JS Helper",11984:"Cache2 I/O",11985:"Cookie",11986:"StreamTrans #1",11990:"Worker Launcher",11995:"GLXVsyncThread",12000:"Renderer",12003:"WRWorker#2",12001:"WRWorker#0",12004:"WRWorker#3",12006:"WRWorker#5",12007:"WRWorker#6",12002:"WRWorker#1",12005:"WRWorker#4",12010:"WRWorkerLP#1",12009:"WRWorkerLP#0",12008:"WRWorker#7",12011:"WRWorkerLP#2",12012:"WRWorkerLP#3",12013:"WRWorkerLP#4",12015:"WRWorkerLP#6",12014:"WRWorkerLP#5",12016:"WRWorkerLP#7",12017:"Compositor",12018:"ImageIO",12019:"IPDL Background",12024:"DOM Worker",12025:"QuotaManager IO",12028:"TRR Background",12039:"StyleThread#4",12037:"StyleThread#2",12035:"StyleThread#0",12038:"StyleThread#3",12036:"StyleThread#1",12040:"StyleThread#5",12041:"ImageBridgeChld",12045:"Breakpad Server",12047:"IPC Launch",12049:"GMPThread",12051:"FS Broker 12048",12052:"ProcessHangMon",12054:"FS Broker 12053",12056:"TaskController Thread #0",12058:"TaskController Thread #2",12057:"TaskController Thread #1",12059:"TaskController Thread #3",12062:"TaskController Thread #6",12060:"TaskController Thread #4",12061:"TaskController Thread #5",12063:"BgIOThreadPool #1",12065:"DOM Worker",12066:"BackgroundThreadPool #2",12068:"DNS Resolver #1",12069:"DNS Resolver #2",12070:"Cache I/O",12073:"FS Broker 12071",12074:"URL Classifier",12075:"DOM Worker",12077:"mozStorage #1",12078:"localStorage DB",12079:"localStorage DB",12081:"HTML5 Parser",12086:"DNS Resolver #3",12087:"DNS Resolver #4",12088:"DNS Resolver #5",12091:"mozStorage #2",12092:"mozStorage #3",12100:"mozStorage #5",12106:"mozStorage #6",12109:"FS Broker 12108",12113:"Shutdown Hang Terminator",12130:"StreamTrans #9",
Throttleable: 1
TotalPageFile: 18368561152
TotalPhysicalMemory: 16368930816
URL: about:blank
UptimeTS: 68.4191473
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 89.0
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Comment: what happens if you install FF and do nothing else as a first step? What version of FF is being installed, how are you installing it and what version/flavour of ubuntu are you using. Please [edit] your question, do not add the information to the comment trail.

Comment: added the ubuntu and firefox versions in the question