# Firefox displays a white screen

Tags: firefox

Firefox version 92
Ubuntu version 20.04

Everything was working fine ~6 months ago the last time I booted Ubuntu. 6 months of updates was installed and after completing the updates my firefox installation on startup displays a blank white screen without an address bar just a blank white window. I attempted a clean reinstall which did not change anything.

Any suggestions on how to fix my firefox installation?

Edit1: firefox was installed with `sudo apt-get install firefox`

Comment: I believe you need to delete Firefox completely and reinstall it from scratch. [this reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed/16773#16773) shows how.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I opened up the profile manager and the windows for it bug out like the firefox windows. The background is transparent and when opening up any additional windows the windows merge and are very difficult to read. I believe this is connected to the issues I am having with firefox itself. I was able to delete and recreate my profile though and it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Maybe it's caused by Hardware acceleration or another problem. Have you tried typing `firefox -safe-mode` in the terminal? First click on _Open_ if it doesn't work, rerun the command and click on _Refresh Firefox_. More info at [Mozilla support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems).

Comment: which version of Firefox do you have? the apt version or the snap? Please [edit] your question accordingly as this will be significant as to which method you use to delete FF leading to a vanilla re-installation

Comment: I have edited my op. Firefox was installed through apt not snap nor through unpacking the executable from mozilla's website.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was resolved thanks to **Gounou**'s help with accessing safe mode through `firefox -safe-mode` from the terminal. Thanks to this I was able to disable hardware acceleration from the options menu which solved my issues.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. There is also the _Troubleshooting Information_ menu when you go to `about:support` (in the address bar - when the screen isn't blank!)
For example, if Firefox is slow to start you can click on `Clear startup cache` in `about:support`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!

Fo me it worked!

Maybe it's caused by Hardware acceleration or another problem. Have you tried typing firefox -safe-mode in the terminal? First click on Open if it doesn't work, rerun the command and click on Refresh Firefox. More info at Mozilla support. – Gounou