# Double Firefox icons and can't uninstall Firefox after upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 21.10

Tags: apt, firefox, 21.10

I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10. After upgrading, I noticed I had 2 Firefox icons. So, I decided to reinstall it. I tried

```
sudo apt purge firefox && sudo apt autoremove
```

But, it only removed **one** icon. After that, I logged out and logged back in. But, It didn't help. Then, I tried,

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep firefox
```

and uninstalled all the packages. It still didn't work. So, I followed this question's answer, [Removing Firefox in Ubuntu with all add-ons like it never existed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed). It didn't help either.
Now, if I try,

```
firefox -v
```

I get the version of firefox & I can open firefox from `Applications`. But, if I try uninstalling firefox again, I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'firefox' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How, do I uninstall Firefox? I'm asking this question from Google Chrome.

Comment: It seems to me, the problem is not firefox package, but you had two different dekstop entries for firefox. Try `sudo find / -type f -name "firefox*.desktop"` and see if it comes with anything.

Comment: @Liso Hello, I can open firefox even after this steps. And, as you asked, If I try, `sudo find / -type f -name "firefox*.desktop"`, I get


`/snap/firefox/631/firefox.desktop
/snap/firefox/631/meta/gui/firefox.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied`

Comment: An upgrade from 20.04 should currently only take you to 21.04 (ie. next *supported* release) - so you've gone outside of the intended upgrade paths.  Your issue is likely the consequence of how you forced your *unsupported* upgrade..  If moving from 21.04 to 21.10; in some cases no `firefox` changes occur; in others the *deb* package gets removed & replaced by a `firefox` snap; but 20.04 to 21.10 isn't supported yet (and won't be till 21.04 reaches EOL)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your reply, I see you still have snap version of firefox. Try uninstalling it.

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. From where should I reinstall firefox now? APT or SNAP ?

Comment: Well if you ask me, I prefer apt over snap, it's easier to manage and I'm more familiar with it. But the choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ^_^