# Ubuntu 22.04 Deleted Firefox but it STILL comes up when I click website links in email. Why?

Tags: firefox, 22.04, brave

Just installed Ubuntu 22.04. Firefox browser was installed with the upgrade. I use Brave browser and search engine only. I found the terminal window command to remove Firefox and executed it. (Tried a second time to confirm removal. Response was that Firefox is indeed removed).

BUT (even after reboot) when I click on links in emails, Firefox still comes up. What is happening? (BTW, Clicking on Brave setting for "default" browser did not take.)  I only want Brave to come up when website links are clicked. Thanks or any help.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact commands you input to delete Firefox and the exact output that was produced. Firefox is a snap in 22.04 so the old means of deleting it in the terminal don't work. You probably removed the .deb that installed the snap.

Comment: I used terminal command sudo snap remove firefox. Afterward I realized that installed Ubuntu software listing still showed Firefox. I was slow to catch on. I was able to delete the software right there. It should have been my first try. Now I find no trace of Firefox. Thatnks for taking the time to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed) on how to remove Firefox from Ubuntu and for setting Brave as the default Browser: you have to go to settings, scroll down on the left side to Default Applications and set Brave as default for Web, that should do the trick. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to remove Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04 is `sudo snap remove firefox`. Then you can change the default web browser in the Settings app -> *Default Applications* from Firefox to Brave web  browser and it will work.

[image]