# How to uninstall Firefox package downloaded from Mozilla

Tags: firefox, uninstall

I use Brave browser in Ubuntu to access nsandi.com bank web page but today I received an error that it was taking to long to download the web page.

I checked nsandi.com's web page and they have instigated two factor security which requires particular browsers and OS. Linux Brave was not among them.

I also had Firefox installed in Ubuntu via snap but it was not the latest version required by nsandi.com. I uninstalled the snap version, downloaded and installed the latest package from Mozilla, following the instructions on their download page. Lo and behold, it was the same version as that I had uninstalled from the snap.

nsandi.com think they may have a problem and are looking into it, so, after all, if the problem is their end then the snap version may work.

I cannot find the same Mozilla instructions I used but this is what I did:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
tar -xf /home/makem/Desktop/firefox-115.0.2.tar.bz2
tar -xf /home/makem/Desktop/firefox-115.0.2.tar.bz2 --directory ~/bin
```

The executable is ~/bin/firefox/firefox

I would like to uninstall that package and reinstall the snap from repos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Firefox in Ubuntu with all add-ons like it never existed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed)

Comment: You should have followed [these instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux). How did you installed firefox ?

Comment: Also, have a look in your command history with `history`

Comment: From 'history' I find the commands used to install Firefox were: 319  mkdir -p ~/bin
  320  tar -xf /home/makem/Desktop/firefox-115.0.2.tar.bz2
  321  tar -xf /home/makem/Desktop/firefox-115.0.2.tar.bz2 --directory ~/bin

Comment: "*I also had Firefox installed in Ubuntu via snap but it was not the latest version....*" That's very suspicious, since the Firefox snap comes directly from Mozilla, and folks on the correct channel *always* have the latest. Use `snap info firefox` to see which versions are available and which channel you are using.

Comment: I have the latest stable 115.0.2-1. There are beta, edge and esr versions.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `~/bin` directory with:

```
rm -r ~/bin
```

You shouldn't use this directory name to put the application, it's confusing. See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I was a little surprised to see the /bin suggestion.